# Double reputation for tag wiki edits

Tags: discussion, reputation, tag-wiki

I've just made my first two edits to tag wikis. And each time I received two simultaneous notifications of

> +2 Tag Wiki suggested edit was approved

[image: Tag Wiki edits]

This seems to be because changes were made to both the Excerpt and the Description sections. Is this really correct behavior? I feel like it should only provide +2 for that single submitted edit.

Answer (score 12):

Yes that is correct, and you'll see this in action in the Suggested Edits review queue where each is independently reviewed.

**But why is it treated as two edits?**

Because the excerpt is shown separately from the main tag description

[image]

and is edited independently:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I would call that any more 'independent' than *Ask a Question*'s Title and Body